# An algorithm to find the well oriented normal of a polygon

Tags: 3d, polygons

I have polygons in 3D which are supposed to be each planar and each coded as a vector of the vertices they are composed of. Polygons can be convex or concave but have no holes.

In these vectors, the vertices are ordered so that they counterclockwise trace the perimeter of the polygon in the right order.

To determinate the normal of a polygon, I have coded the algorithm below.

Is this algorithm mathematically correct? Is there a more efficient one?

```
A polygon vector is [V0, ...., Vp].

For each n in [1, p-1], calculate Nn = cross product of (V0,Vn) and (V0, Vn+1).

Make the sum S of all Nn.

S give the wanted orientation (or -S depending on a convention).
```

Comment: Looks good to me, although you only need to have $n$ go up to $p-1$. You're essentially computing the polygon's [vector area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_area). Don't forget to normalize it at the end.

Comment: @Rahul  Thanks, I see the idea for vector area. And yes p-1, you're right.

Comment: If the polygon is indeed planar, why do you need more than three successive (non-colinear) vertices to compute a normal for it?

Comment: @amd, because of concavities... or if I miss something please, explain more.

Comment: @amd: If you're unlucky and choose three vertices that form a concave vertex, you'll get the wrong sign for the normal.

Comment: So, there’s a convention that you’ve not made explicit when you talk about *the* normal.